# Time Machine menu in system preferences shows no backups

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

Time Machine is saying that this computer has never been backed up... but it has!

[image: System Preferences]

When I enter the time machine, I can still access backups.

[image: Time Machine]

I checked `tmutil machinedirectory` and it points to a valid directory on the external hard drive containing all my backups. `tmutil destinationinfo` refers to the external hard drive. Most importantly, `tmutil latestbackup` refers to the latest backup on the hard drive.

I think I might need to run `tmutil associatedisk` or `tmutil inheritbackup` but I don't want to risk corrupting my backups without knowing more.

---

I tried running `tmutil inheritbackup machine_directory` (because it seemed less scary than `associatedisk`) and I got this:

```
Usage: tmutil inheritbackup machine_directory
       tmutil inheritbackup sparse_bundle
machine_directory: Invalid target
```

I'm not really sure what `Invalid target` means.

I've been reading the man page entry for `associatedisk` and I'm about 70% sure that it's what I'm looking for but it seems like a destructive operation and I don't want to mess it up.

Some important information that I should have mentioned, **my hard drive was recently wiped clean and I reinstalled macOS**. The last three backups are from Catalina (so everything is split into `Macintosh HD` and `Macintosh HD — Data`) but I'm running Mojave.

---

If all my backups were from Mojave or earlier then I think this is what I'm after:

```
sudo tmutil associatedisk -a "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" "/Volumes/Time Machine/Backups.backupdb/Indi-Mac/Latest/Macintosh HD"
```

...but my most recent three backups are from Catalina so this might cause problems. I might need to do this for the Catalina backups:

```
sudo tmutil associatedisk "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" "/Volumes/Time Machine/Backups.backupdb/Indi-Mac/<date>/Macintosh HD — Data"
```

...and then this for the rest:

```
sudo tmutil associatedisk "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" "/Volumes/Time Machine/Backups.backupdb/Indi-Mac/<date>/Macintosh HD"
```

Is it enough to use `associatedisk` on the latest backup? I'm really not sure about this. I really don't want to mess it up. Am I asking this question in the right place?

---

I ran the `associatedisk` commands that I described above. It didn't solve the problem. The `Macintosh HD — Data` directories were renamed to `Macintosh HD 1` and I can't change them back. I don't actually think this matters too much since I didn't really do much in the time that I was using Catalina so I could delete the Catalina backups if that's what's messing everything up. I can recall a short list of things that I changed and I've already copied them out.

Is it possible to recover from the mess I've created? I should have never "upgraded" to Catalina. Actually, going back to Mojave was equally regrettable. I'm guessing that if went back to Catalina and ran `associatedisk`, I'd fix the Catalina backup.

This is a nightmare.

---

I'm not sure what will happen if I click the "Back Up Now" button. Where will the backup go? How will it relate to the existing backups?

Comment: Which TM snapshot did you use to restore your data (after clean installing Mojave)?

Comment: @klanomath I used the latest Catalina backup. I was having boot issues after trying to restore the latest Mojave backup so I decided to start fresh. I downloaded and installed applications instead of copying from the backup. I made sure to only restore the things I needed and not entire top-level directories. I left behind about 30 GB of random junk that had accumulated over the years. Maybe I should give up trying to fix this backup disk and start fresh with that too? It's as if I went out and bought a new laptop!

Comment: Did you only restore single user files/directories unrelated to Apple stuff (i.e. your Mail folder/iTunes/Music Library)? Some libs (e.g. iTunes/Music) changed format/content and the Catalina version of a lib is incompatible with its Mojave version.

Comment: @klanomath Oh yeah, I restored my iTunes library from the Mojave backup. Other than that, I think everything is pretty clean. I don't see how that relates to the question though.

Comment: I would either delete the 3 Catalina snapshots and try to inherit/associate the last Mojave snapshot **or** start a fresh TM backup - keeping the old snapshots for a while and later (after a few month) delete them. Relation to the question: Can I recommend to start a new TM backup/delete single Catalina snapshots and/or delete **all** older backups.

Comment: @klanomath Hmm, yeah that's sort of what I was thinking.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this problem?

Comment: @JasonK I did end up solving this but I don't remember what I did unfortunately. I should have came back here and wrote an answer but I must have been so relieved to get it working that I forgot! I'm sorry I can't be of any help.